# Discord.py NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm learning python and i'm developing a discord bot. I want to make an auto-role system but it's showing that 'ctx' is not defined. Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

server = ctx.message.server


perms = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.create_role(server, name='Unverified', permissions=perms)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Unverified')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Well, you _didn't_ define it anywhere in your code. `ctx` is usually the context that is passed to a command (see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)

Comment: What are you attempting to do with this line :`server = ctx.message.server`?

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because ctx is not defined anywhere check this code to understand how ctx value work in commands there is other ways to do it but me I do it like that :

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hello')
```

This was a basic command with use ctx if you wanna to put your value you have to use it into the "@client.command"

Answer (score 0):

As @PranavHosangadi said in the comments, `ctx` needs to be defined. It is not an object that is inherited/included when importing the `discord` module.